# How can I reference a CSS stylesheet in the default index.html file to work with both the default url and the url with index.html?

Tags: html, css

I have an index.html and a stylesheet CSS file which I want to use with the index.html.
The index.html references the stylesheet with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
```

However this only works for the URL that includes index.html in it:

```
HTTP://server/system/webdev/proj/index.html
```

When I try the default URL without index.html, I get a 404 and it's looking for the stylesheet inside of the `webdev` folder:

```
HTTP://server/system/webdev/proj
```

How can I make it work for both URLs?

Edit:
it *does* work for URL: `HTTP://server/system/webdev/proj/` with ending `/`

Can I make it work for the URL *without* the ending `/` as well as the others?

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a good idea to reference style sheets (and other external resources) with the full absolute URL. That way the relationship between the HTML file and the style sheet become irrelevant:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="HTTP://server/system/webdev/proj/stylesheet.css">
```